# Trying to fetch Latitude and Longitude data from Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

So im trying to show marker on google map based on lat and long data from  my firebase

My Firebase Structure is like these:

[image: Firebase Database]

Now this is my code to show marker

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mReff=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("01");
        mReff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String lat =s.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                    String lng =s.child("longitude").getValue().toString();

                    double latitude=Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    double longitude=Double.parseDouble(lng);
                    LatLng lokasi = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lokasi).title(s.child("nama").getValue().toString()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

But im always get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.proyekakhir.Aplikasi, PID: 1583
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.proyekakhir.Aplikasi.Lacak$1.onDataChange(Lacak.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:184)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:442)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: can you try to put firebase code on oncreate() and try out ?

Comment: I have tried it and it still give me error

Comment: @nauzifikri In the your firebase structure you have only "Latitude" and "Longitude" under "01" key , and you are trying to access  
s.child("nama").getValue()  with toString() method but your "nama" value is null so you cannot call a method from null value, please check that out.

Comment: So i delete that s.child(“nama”).getValue but it still gave me the same error

Comment: @nauzifikri  It is possible that your not getting your latitude and longitude value both or one of them, check your code by debugging.

Comment: Yea i tried to debug it,and it always gave me the same error ,so im wondering if there are any wrong line or where im wrong in the code above

Comment: please verify you are getting the value by debugging when you come in  the above method, add debug on for loop starting line.
s.child("latitude").getValue()
s.child("longitude").getValue()

Comment: check that your dataSnapshot have values that you are trying to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mReff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       HashMap<String, Double> data = (HashMap<String, Double>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
       double latitude = data.get("latitude");
       double longitude = data.get("longitude");
      // your further code.
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
    });
```

Comment: i tried it, and it gives me error  error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to HashMap<String,Double>

Comment: @nauzi check my updated answer with typecast.. I have tested it is working

Comment: i cant upvote sadly i dont have 15 reputation but i can accept the answer thank u sir

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use that for loop, because you have already set the reference to `01` node.

```java
mReff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       double latitude = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
       double longitude = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
       LatLng lokasi = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
       mMap.addMarker(new 
       MarkerOptions().position(lokasi).title("Title"));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
    });
```

Comment: So i tried it but it gives me error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to double